# Swiftmailer syntax error

Tags: php, swiftmailer

My swiftmailer keeps giving me the  syntax error: unexpected '->'  (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in the line`->setTo = (array('email@gmail.com', 'email2@yahoo.com'))` see code below.

What have I done wrong?

```
<?php
  require_once 'swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

  $to="toemail@gmail.com";
  $subject="Band Request";
  $user_message = $_POST[text];
  $name = $_POST[name];
  $email = $_POST[email];
  $band_request =$_POST[uploaded_file];

  $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()

    ->setSbuject = ($subject)
    ->setTo = (array('email@gmail.com', 'email2@yahoo.com'))
    ->setFrom = ($email)
    ->setBody = ($user_message)
    ->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($band_request))

  ;



  $email_message = "Email: ".$email."\nMessage: ".$message;
  //Set Transport
  $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost');
  //Set Mailer
  $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
    // Send the message
  $numSent = $mailer->send($message);

  printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

  echo "Band Request form has been submitted. <br><a href='../index.html'>Back Home</a>";

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the equal sign after `setSubject` like so:

```
->setSubject($subject)
```

`setSubject` is a method, not a property.

(Oh and by the way, you have a typo in `setSubject` as well: `setSbuject`.)